# How to check node-mongodb-native driver version?

Tags: npm, node-mongodb-native

I am using official node-mongodb-native driver in my project.
Which was installed by doing npm install mongodb. However I want to check its version but not sure how to do so.

There is nothing in the READ.ME file of that npm repo.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/list.html) you can get a list of npm packages and their corresponding versions using `npm ls` or `npm ls -g` (for global)

Comment: Thanks. This is answer applies to all npm modules and I can easily check version of any module going forward.

Comment: `npm ls` will list out **all** packages, you may be in an ocean of package, so it's better to be specific.

Answer (score 2):

The version is exported in [`index.js`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/index.js#L9):

```
exports.version = require('../../package').version;
```

So you can get it by requiring the module and accessing the `version` property:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var version = mongo.version;

console.log(version);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but i like the answer given below by Ashoka which gives version of any module by doing npm ls.

Comment: They no longer export the version :'( https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/index.js

Answer (score 1):

as of this writing, you can simply `npm view <package-name> version` (use `show` in place of `view` will work too).
for example to find out my mongodb module/driver version, `npm view mongodb version`

Comment: Works perfectly fine as expected

Comment: It doesn't show the version of my installed module. It shows the latest version of the module in NPM.

Answer (score 0):

> It's late answer, hope it may useful for others.

The simple way to get `MongoDB version` or `MongoDB native driver`

```
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
if (err) throw err;
client.admin().serverInfo()
    .then(info => {
        console.log(info.version);
        console.log(client.serverConfig.clientInfo.driver.version);
    }).catch(err => { });
});
```