# Get the MongoDB server version from node-mongodb-native in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This seems like a really easy thing and I wonder if this is my least clever question here on Stack Overflow.

I would like to figure out the version of the MongoDB server that [`node-mongodb-native`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) is connected to.

However, I cannot seem to find anything regarding this using google. It's not the same as `require('mongodb').version`; this holds the node module verion.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683280/how-to-check-node-mongodb-native-driver-version

Comment: Nope. That is about the npm package version (`mongo.version`). I want to find out the MongoDB server version. E.g. `2.6.10`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the [`serverStatus`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverStatus.version) database command to retrieve the version of the `mongod` or `mongos` instance you're connected to.

The native node.js driver provides the [`Admin.serverStatus`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/admin.html#serverstatus) for that purpose:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
var conn = MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var adminDb = db.admin();
    adminDb.serverStatus(function(err, info) {
        console.log(info.version);
    })
})
```

Displaying on my system:

```
3.0.2
```

Comment: This now appears to be `adminDb.serverInfo()` in the latest version of the driver